# Vulkan WaW hazard & memory barrier

Tags: vulkan, gpu, memory-barriers

Vulkan spec states:

> Write-after-read hazards can be solved with just an execution dependency, but read-after-write and write-after-write hazards need appropriate memory dependencies to be included between them.

I thought that WaW can be solved with only execution barrier as well.
Why do we need a memory barrier to solve WaW hazard if we're not going to read data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Execution dependencies ensure the ordering of operations. Memory dependencies ensure the *visibility* of memory operations. These aren't the same thing.

In order for a write-after-write to work correctly, the second write has to happen after the first write, but also you have to make sure that the first write is visible to the operation doing the second write. Otherwise, it's possible for the second write to be overwritten by the first, even if the second write happened after the first.

If you want a more hardware-based explanation, consider what happens if the first write uses one cache, and the second write uses a separate cache from the first (GPUs have a lot of caches). Execution dependencies don't affect caches. So the second write's cache may write its data before the first write's cache does, which means that the first write will eventually overwrite the second.

Memory dependencies force data out of caches, thus ensuring that when the second write takes place, there isn't a write sitting around in a cache somewhere.

Comment: And what other thing than memory side effects constitutes execution order? In other words when it is important to have a particular execution order without the need to have memory dependency? Or where only having memory dependency is not enough?

Comment: @listerreg: For example, if you have two operations, a read followed by a write. If the read comes first, you don't need a memory dependency between the two; there is nothing to make visible to the write operation. All you need to do is ensure that the read happens before the write. The quote from the spec in the question specifies this.

Comment: @listerreg: "*Or where only having memory dependency is not enough?*" I don't know what you mean by this. You cannot have a memory dependency that is *separate* from an execution dependency. Visibility *requires* ordering.

Comment: What would be a concrete example of a WaW operation? Is it correct that two subsequent draw calls with graphics pipelines which use the _same_ depth buffer would _not_ classify as a WaW hazard but rather as a RaW hazard w.r.t. the depth buffer?